# Find if specific edge not includes in any MST

Tags: algorithm, graph

I have a question about MST and directed-Graph.
Let's say there is a Graph G with weight function w: E -> R and also there is edge e from E group (u,v).
I need to find algorithm in o(E+V) that check if e is not includes in any MST.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using numbers as weights, use vectors of pairs of numbers as weights.  Addition is componentwise.  Comparisons are on the first number, breaking ties on the second.  (Very conveniently, that is the default rule for how Python compares tuples for inequality.)

Assign to each edge `x` a weight of `(w(x), 0)`.  But assign to your special element `e` the weight `(w(e), -1)`.

Now search for the MST.  The MST will contain `e` if and only if your original graph had an MST containing `e`.